# how to load directory data into hive

Tags: file, hive, load, hdfs

how to load  hdfs files into hive. in my project, it need to load hdfs files  into hive. My hdfs files structure like `/flume/topic/date/hour/file.hdfs``, the question is how I can load directory data automatic.

Comment: yes, I used partition table to sovle this application.

Comment: have you meet the same proplem?

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Directory contains three files

     -rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup        125 2017-05-15 17:53/hallfolder/hall.csv
     -rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup        125 2017-05-15 17:53/hallfolder/hall1.csv
     -rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup        125 2017-05-15 17:54/hallfolder/hall2.csv
2) Enable this command

     hive > SET mapred.input.dir.recursive=true;
3) hive>

     hive>load data  inpath '/hallfolder/*' into table alltable;
```